# Shorthand for checking if associative array not null and if key exists

Tags: php

Is there any way of checking if a variable is not null and then to check if variable has nested associative array keys using a shorthand? Something like optional chaining for associative arrays?

Example of what I would like to make concise:

```
public $arr;

//$arr gets set as an associative array somewhere else in the code.

function someFunc() {
   if ($this->arr && $this->arr['key1'] && $this->arr['key1']['key2'] == 'Some Value') { // shorten this line?
      // Do Something Cool!
   }
}
```

I am looking for something similar to Optional Chaining in Javascript e.g. :

```
if (obj.key1?.key2 == 'Some Value') { 
    // Do something kool
}
```

There is a high probability that this is a duplicate and I apologize in advance if that is the case. I tried searching for this for associative arrays and could not find anything specific.

Comment: In PHP/8 you have it for objects, but not for arrays.

Comment: Though this condition could be reduced to `isset($array['key1']['key2']) && $array['key1']['key2'] === 'Some value'`.

Comment: just use `isset`

Comment: I am aware of `isset` was looking for something shorter as mentioned above.

Comment: why do you need something shorter? what problem are you trying to solve by shortening it even more beyond `isset`?

Comment: @james Combining an `isset` with a comparison seems to be the end goal. Coola, you can always write your own custom function that performs both of these conditions if you want to shorten it.

Comment: Thanks I needed something short as I said these conditions seem to be repeating many times in my current code. Making a separate function to do this just makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the php function `isset`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

It will check for multiple keys: `if( isset($this->arr['key1']['key2'] ) {...}` and also includes a null check.

If you for some reason need to shorten it even more, simply decompose it to another function:

```
    public $arr;

//$arr gets set as an associative array somewhere else in the code.

    function someFunc()
    {
        if ($this->checkForSomeValue($this->arr, 'Some Value', 'key1', 'key2')) { // shorten this line?
            // Do Something Cool!
        }
    }

    function checkForSomeValue(array $arr, string $valueToCheck, ...$keys)
    {
        $valueCompare = $arr;
        foreach($keys as $key)
        {
            if(!isset($valueCompare[$key]))
            {
                $valueCompare = null;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                $valueCompare = $valueCompare[$key];
            }
        }

        return $valueCompare && $valueCompare === $valueToCheck;
    }
```

I've updated the answer to allow supplying keys

Comment: Thanks - I think creating a custom function just makes more sense. Is it possible to have the function work with various 'key' parameters and to different depths in the nesting?

Comment: @Coola that gets more tricky, let me see.... you could consider using variable length arguments: `function(...$keys) {...}`, but would need some looping to continually check the `$arr` depth

Comment: Thanks James. If you can think of something please update the answer. I hope you understand now my inclination for simpler optional chaining as it would be much easier to write and read inline what is happening in the code.

Comment: @Coola i've updated the answer. you can supply multiple keys to the `checkForSomeValue` function now. i think the logic is a bit hard to read, though. could be improved for better ability to maintain

Comment: Wouldn't the function need to be recursive one for nested keys?

Comment: @Coola hmm, I think not based on your example of how you'd use it. this can be used when the depth of the array (`$arr`) is known, based on how many keys you supply. if you supply 2 keys, it will loop through those exact 2 keys `$arr[$key1][$key2]`, if you supplied 4 it will loop exactly four times: `$arr[$key1][$key2][$key3][$key4]` ... etc. the important line is `$valueCompare = $valueCompare[$key];`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226255/discussion-between-james-and-coola).

Answer (score 2):

You could keep the if statement intact, but replace `$this->arr && $this->arr['key1']` with an [Null Coalescing Operator (`??`)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php7/php7_coalescing_operator.htm), so if those aren't defined, it will use the fallback, that isn't equal to the test string:

```
if (($this->arr['key1']['key2'] ?? false) == 'Some Value') {
  // Do Something Cool!
}
```

So if `$this->arr['key1']['key2']` is defined, you'll compare that to `Some Value`, otherwise, if it's not defined, you'll compare (eg) `false` to `Some Value` witch will remain `false`.

Comment: I've often found this null coalescing operator to be harder to read